# gsub remove everything before the first comma

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have this string:

```
auteur = "comte de Flandre et Hainaut, Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
```

I want to remove everything before the first comma i.e. in this case keep "Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"

Tried this :

```
nom = auteur.gsub(/.*,/, '')
```

But that removes every before the last comma and keeps only "Thierry".

Answer (score 10):

```
auteur.partition(",").last
# => " Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
```

Comment: You should mention that this returns the whole string if no comma is present in `auteur`.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke That is "everything before the first comma" removed, which is exactly what the OP was asking for.

Comment: It is better to be more explicit than leaving something to interpretation. I could argue that the first comma in a string without a comma is *after* the string and so an empty string should be returned. It depends on the use case which the OP did not specify enough to decide that.

Comment: "[T]he first comma in a string without a comma is after the string"--That is self-contradictory in at least two senses. (1) A string without a comma has no (first) comma. You can claim the existence of a comma outside of the string, but that is not the original string's comma. (2) Even if there were any comma outside of the string in question, there is no basis to discuss any order relation with that comma and any position within the original string. It does not make sense.

Answer (score 8):

Use `#sub` instead of `#gsub` to remove only the first occurrence and make the repetition lazy (`?`):

```
auteur = "comte de Flandre et Hainaut, Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
nom = auteur.sub(/.*?,/, '') # => " Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
```

---

Or don't use regexes at all (returns the original string if no commas are present):

```
auteur.split(',', 2).last # => " Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
```

Comment: Your `split` solution also works without a comma present. In that case, the return is the original full string.

Comment: @HolgerJust, true, but it's just unclear what is the expected behaviour in that case. I'll add a clarification.

Comment: Fails on `"Hi man,\nplease, see an attachment"`. The rule of thumb: always use `\A` not `^` matcher when working with possibly multiline strings.

Comment: @mudasobwa, agree. That is why I mentioned it's the *beginning of **line***. But I also don't subscribe to the school of thought that rubyists should use `\A`/`\z` by default. The variable was named `auteur` (meaning author) so I assume the name and the titles shouldn't spread on multiple lines. Yet, this could be user input so who knows. This is a valuable comment, I hope OP reads it and gives his feedback on whether or not this is a (possibly) multiline string.

Comment: @mudasobwa, actually it wasn't needed at all. Updated my answer.

Comment: Once I will write a great book (it will be a bestseller etc.) on what assumptions should be made on user input consistency. It is to be published in embossed cover and be a handbook for everybody. The content would be the single word “NONE” printed in  a very bold :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I wasn't saying we should make assumptions about user input. Or are you being super meta and consider OP's question as user input of SO? xd

Answer (score 1):

You can use a positive lookbehind for the first comma then something like this with `[]` notation:

```
nom = auteur[/(?<=\,\s).*/]
#=> "Baudouin, Jacques, Thierry"
```